# Copy specific cell in multiple workbook to one wok book using vba

Tags: excel, vba

Hello please help me yo solve this.

I have multiple workbook and I want to copy a specific cell in each workbook into another workbook orderly.

Great thanks

Sophannaa

Answer (score 0):

Copy this whole code to the list of your choice(to visual basic of course).
Run this by running begin().
Change values in part"HERE COMES YOUR PART!!!"

```
    Sub begin()
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    DoEvents
    Const ROW_FIRST As Integer = 5
    Dim intResult As Integer
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim intCountRows As Integer
    Dim sourceWB As Workbook
    Dim targetWB As Workbook
    Set targetWB = ThisWorkbook
    Dim xrow As Integer
    xrow = 5

    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Title = "Please select File to load"
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).ButtonName = "Choose a file"
    intResult = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show

    For Each Item In Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems
        If intResult <> 0 Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Range("A:A").ClearContents
            Range("B:B").ClearContents
            Range("C:C").ClearContents
            Cells(4, 1).Value = "NAME"
            Cells(4, 2).Value = "PATH"
            Cells(4, 3).Value = "TAIL"
            strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)

            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            intCountRows = GetAllFiles(strPath, ROW_FIRST, objFSO)
            Call GetAllFolders(strPath, objFSO, intCountRows)
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End If
    Next Item

    Cells(1, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B")) - 1
'HERE COMES YOUR PART!!!


     Dim nextrow As Integer
        nextrow = 2 'choose starting row where to copy the results
        Do
            strFile = Cells(xrow, 2).Value
            Set sourceWB = Workbooks.Open(strFile)
            targetWB.Sheets("desired sheet to copy to").Cells(nextrow, 1) = sourceWB.Sheets("desired sheet to copy from").Cells(2, 1)
            'instead of cells(2,1)                      up here       ^^                                                 and here^^ choose what cells you want to copy from, edit only numbers
            sourceWB.Save
            sourceWB.Close
            xrow = xrow + 1
            nextrow = nextrow + 1
        Loop Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(xrow, 2).Value = ""
        End Sub

        Private Function GetAllFiles(ByVal strPath As String, ByVal intRow As Integer, ByRef objFSO As Object) As Integer
        DoEvents
        Dim objFolder As Object
        Dim objFile As Object
        Dim i As Integer


        i = intRow - ROW_FIRST + 1
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)

        For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
            inte = InStr(1, objFile.Name, "prázdný")
                        Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 1) = objFile.Name
                        Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 2) = objFile.Path
                        Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 3) = Right(objFile.Name, Len(objFile.Name) - InStrRev(objFile.Name, "."))
                        i = i + 1
        Next objFile
        GetAllFiles = i + ROW_FIRST - 1

        End Function

        Private Sub GetAllFolders(ByVal strFolder As String, ByRef objFSO As Object, ByRef intRow As Integer)
        DoEvents
        Dim objFolder As Object
        Dim objSubFolder As Object
        Static veSpravneSlozce As Boolean
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)
        For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
                intRow = GetAllFiles(objSubFolder.Path, intRow, objFSO)
                Call GetAllFolders(objSubFolder.Path, objFSO, intRow)
        Next objSubFolder
        End Sub
```

Since it is really useless to copy all values to one cell a added nextrow to shift cells and write down values one after another